# Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarExceptionUnable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

when I connect spring boot and ms sql server I got the following error. when I remove the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency this is working fine. please help looking through this error.

error

```html
2022-01-26 11:03:33.405  WARN 15056 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 18456, SQLState: S0001
2022-01-26 11:03:33.405 ERROR 15056 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Login failed for user 'sa'. ClientConnectionId:eab49648-e559-44e0-b8c0-5ab8c1fba774
2022-01-26 11:03:33.417 ERROR 15056 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
2022-01-26 11:03:33.419  WARN 15056 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
2022-01-26 11:03:33.421  INFO 15056 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-01-26 11:03:33.435  INFO 15056 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-01-26 11:03:33.467 ERROR 15056 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
at com.ont.hospitalmicroservice.HospitalMicroserviceApplication.main(HospitalMicroserviceApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.processTableResultSet(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.AbstractInformationExtractorImpl.getTables(AbstractInformationExtractorImpl.java:555) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTablesInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'. ClientConnectionId:eab49648-e559-44e0-b8c0-5ab8c1fba774
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:265) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:287) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:129) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:37) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:5560) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:4289) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:88) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:4227) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7417) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3488) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2978) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2628) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2471) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1470) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:915) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
... 36 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=drne_new;
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=abc123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
server.port=8083
spring.application.name=hospital-microservice
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone= http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Comment: please put the stacktrace here and not an image because we can't fully read it.


But as a first suggestion I would advise to remove this line from the spring boot data jpa starter : 
 <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>

Comment: @VladucuVoican Thank you for your contribution. I added stack trace here please check it. I removed the spring boot data jpa starter version. Still this error came. please give proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

On what port is your sql server running? You need to mention  it in spring.datasource.url property in applications properties

Comment: Naresh Sharma thank you for your contribution. Sql server running on port 1433. I mentioned port also still same error thrown. Before week ago this was run perfectly. they released spring boot starter data jpa 2.6.3 on January 20 so is any problem in this version?

Comment: What is the version of Sql server? Are you able to login to the database with the same credentials?

Comment: yeah I can able to login with same credentials. sql version 15.0.2000.5

Comment: try this, maybe it works : jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=drne_new;

Comment: no Naresh not working...

Comment: Try changing the dialect to org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

Comment: same error coming after change dialect also...

Comment: I got the solution. I uninstall the sql server and re install it now it is working. thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Please re install sql server. This is working me.